# Rollback yarn command

Tags: command-line-interface, yarnpkg, rollback

Is there way to rollback command `yarn` in CLI?

I want check if on server is yarn so i type to CLI `yarn`...

But immediately i was see:

```
yarn install v1.22.0
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...

success Saved lockfile.
Done in 0.09s.
```

In directory was other direcoties like: `.cache` or `node_modules` and files `.yarnrc`, `yarn.lock`....

Is there way to rollback this command?

Is there some options know what EXACTLY was changed and where?

What was on server and what was installed by yarn?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late reply but in my recent research I found out that this command in the documentation.

```
yarn remove [package]
```

https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/managing-dependencies/